# I need help finding the critical values of this function.

Tags: calculus

So $h(t)=t^{\frac{3}{4}}-7t^{\frac{1}{4}}$. So I need to set $h'(t)=0$. So for $h'(t)$ the fattest I've gotten to simplifying os $h'(t)=\frac{3}{4 \sqrt[4]{t}}-\frac{7}{4\sqrt[4]{t^3}}$ and that is as farthest as I can simplify. So i'm having a had time having $h'=0$ So could someone show me how to properly simplify and find the critical values step by step I would immensely appreciate it. In the most recent material we have covered in class ir seems that my biggest struggle comes from simplifying completely. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Pull out a factor of $\frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{t^3}}$. You know that isn't $0$, so the other factor must be $0$. The other factor looks simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$h'(t)=\frac{3}{4 t^{\frac{1}{4}}}-\frac{7}{4t^{\frac{3}{4}}}=\frac{3t^{\frac{2}{4}}-7}{4t^{\frac{3}{4}}}=\frac{3t^{\frac{1}{2}}-7}{4t^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$

$$h'(t)=0 \Rightarrow 3t^{\frac{1}{2}}-7=0 \Rightarrow t^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{7}{3} \Rightarrow t=\frac{49}{9}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am having trouble understanding how you went from $\frac{3}{4 t^{\frac{1}{4}}}-\frac{7}{4t^{\frac{3}{4}}}->\frac{3t^{\frac{2}{4}}-7} {4t^{\frac{3}{4}}}$ If you could explain I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kenshin Multiply the first fraction by $\frac{t^\frac{1}{2}}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}}$. Now in that denominator $4t^{\frac{1}{4}}t^\frac{1}{2}=4t^{\frac{3}{4}}$, and you can join the two fractions as one.

Comment: Thanks a lot @J.W.Perry! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

$h(t)=t^{\frac{3}{4}}-7t^{\frac{1}{4}}$

$\Rightarrow$ $0=h'(t)=\frac{3}{4}t^{-\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{7}{4}t^{-\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{3}{4}t^{-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{2}{4}}-\frac{7}{4}t^{-\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{3}{4}t^{-\frac{3}{4}}t^{\frac{2}{4}}-\frac{7}{4}t^{-\frac{3}{4}}=t^{-\frac{3}{4}}(\frac{3}{4}t^{\frac{2}{4}}-\frac{7}{4})$

Thus $t=(\frac{7}{3})^2$ Since one factor have to be $0$ and $t^{-\frac{3}{4}}$ is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

To make your life easier, just define $x=t^{\frac{1}{4}}$. So $h(t)=x^3-7x$ and then $$\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{dh}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=(3x^2-7)\frac{dx}{dt}$$ So,$h'(t)=0$ if $x^2=\frac{7}{3}$ that is to say $\sqrt t=\frac{7}{3}$ then $t=\frac{49}{9}$.